# ActiveMQ Message Timestamp - How do I pull Timestamp data using SQL? Where is it stored?

Tags: sql, timestamp, activemq-classic

I am trying to pull the Timestamp data from the ActiveMQ web UI using SQL.

Our `ACTIVEMQ_MSGS` table in the database has the following columns:

```
ID (AMQ message ID)
CONTAINER (which queue the message goes into)
MSGID_PROD
MSGID_SEQ
EXPIRATION
MSG (BLOB containing all message data).
```

Notice there is no timestamp column. I am able to extract SENT_TIME from the message blob but SENT_TIME is not the same as the timestamp in ActiveMQ.

I assume that active MQ timestamp in the web application must be populated through PHP generated HTML that pulls this timestamp from a database. Any idea how I find which database this timestamp is being pulled from?

I would post a screenshot but I don't have enough repuation yet :(

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confident that ActiveMQ stores this as part of its internal message format, since you can also see the timestamp when you use non-persistent messages (they are not stored at all).
So my suggestion would be to manually add a timestamp message property.